# wordpress htaccess doesnt change url, just goes to 404

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)/?$ http://test.com/test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

has no effect in the htaccess file that I am using:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)/?$ http://test.com/test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I visit my domain.com/test/123, Wordpress redirects be to a 404 page not the new link.
I have tried moving the items in the htaccess file around in case they are being overwritten, but not luck. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Problem 1: RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash.
- Problem 2: Wrong order of Rewrite Rules.

Here is the fixed version:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/?$ http://test.com/test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you know why when i change:
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/?$ http://test.com/test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

to RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/?$ /test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC] it no longer works (basically it works with external domains but referring to the site on my server...

Comment: Actually it works but for an external domain it adds `R` automatically. For intern path you can do: `RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/?$ /test/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]` and it will work the way you want.